# Map array with empty argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I want to map array and get indexes in return (currentValue is not needed).
I want to avoid using unused arguments, so is there better way to do this:

```
 array.map((el, index) => { // el is not used anywhere
          return (
          <div>X</div>
          );
        })
```

Comment: People often call the variable `_` in that case.

Comment: You're not using `index`, either.

Comment: And you forgot the `>` at the end of `</div`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your want to use `Array.map` you can use `_` as your value, this way you telling other developers that you don't plan to use that value. like:

```
someArray.map((_, index) => { /* your code */ })
```

Or your can simply use [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop.

Comment: That's fine answer

Answer (score -1):

You have both options

```
Array.map(element, index)
```

As well as

```
Array.map(element)
```